# Trying to use JavaScript file from static resource in VF Page is not working

Tags: jquery, css, static-resources

We have uploaded the following in static resource as a zip file and used it in Visualforce page
 as follows:

**Old Tags**

```
<apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />
<apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
<apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
```

**After adding it to static resource**

**1st Method:**

```
 <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PaginationJS, 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PaginationJS, 'js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PaginationJS, 'css/jquery.dataTables.css')}"/>
```

**2nd Method:**

```
   <apex:includescript value="{!($Resource.PaginationJS, '/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includescript value="{!($Resource.PaginationJS, '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!($Resource.PaginationJS, '/css/jquery.dataTables.css')}"/>
```

**3rd Method:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!$Resource.PaginationJS}"></script>
```

None of the options above are working in Salesforce. Do we have any other options to do so?or is it a wrong tag?Need help

Comment: You're trying to use datatable? Then try loading `jQuery` first, then datatable. Also, are you able to see the files in the "Source" tab in browser developer console?

Comment: Yeah thank you @SE_User. Its working perfectly after loading the jquery first. But what is the reason behind that?and why should we give so?

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted the same as answer. If it solved your issue, you may [mark it as the answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Load `jQuery` first, and then `dataTable`.

```
<apex:includescript value="{!($Resource.PaginationJS, '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includescript value="{!($Resource.PaginationJS, '/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!($Resource.PaginationJS, '/css/jquery.dataTables.css')}"/>
```

It is that, `jQuery` is a prerequisite for `datatable` plugin to work.

> Or in other words, jQuery should first be loaded, only then the
>   datatable would work, since datatable is a jQuery plugin.